# Letsencrypt: Expected </VirtualHost> but saw </VirtualHost></IfModule>

Tags: debian, raspberrypi, apache2.4, letsencrypt

When trying to install new [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates on my raspberry-pi apache 2.4 webserver using `sudo certbot --apache` I get the following error:

```
Error while running apache2ctl configtest.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

apache2: Syntax error on line x of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line x of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xxx-le-ssl.conf: Expected </VirtualHost> but saw </VirtualHost></IfModule>
```

How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the [letsencrypt community](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/error-running-client-expected-virtualhost-but-saw-virtualhost-ifmodule/7276/24) I found a simple solution.

The error originates from **missing newlines** at the end of each enabled (apache) site.
So you either add them to each file in `sites-enabled` or 'sites-available' (both usually located in `/etc/apache2/`) or you can use [Yanson](https://community.letsencrypt.org/users/yanson/activity)'s one liner:

`for f in /etc/apache2/sites-available/*; do sed -i '$a\' "$f"; done`

Comment: For people who use other Linux distros who have this issue: Make sure that the site config file in /etc/httpd/conf.d has a carriage return/new line after the last </VirtualHost>